# I'm replacing my lost UK Passport replacement in US

Tags: usa, passports, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, lost-documents

I have dual US and UK citizenship and I lost my UK Passport and need to replace it. How do I get my new UK Passport? I currently stay in the US.

Comment: Did you look at the UK government website on how to replace your lost passport?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations throughout StackExchange is that you demonstrate some initial research effort; implicitly, questions should be about topics not easily found in a reference. A web search should turn up an official guide to replacing the passport at https://www.gov.uk/renew-adult-passport/overview without difficulty. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: Dear close-voters, as much as I sympathize with you, this questions just shows no research whatsoever, for which you can vote -1. It is not, however, unclear, so stop voting as such. Also be aware that one can retract a close vote by clicking *close* again and then retracting.

Comment: @mts It is so trivially easy to find out this information that it's very difficult to believe that this person's question is truly exactly what was posted. Thus it is "unclear", not because the question itself is unclear, but because the user's intentions are unclear and they probably haven't asked their real question.

Answer (score 5):

The UK government has all the relevant information on its website. See: [Renew or replace your adult passport](https://www.gov.uk/renew-adult-passport/overview). Specifically, you want the information for [Overseas British passport applications](https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports). Follow the steps, choosing "replacing a lost or stolen passport," and it will tell you what you need to do, with links to the application form, guidance, and list of required supporting documents.